# using requests and jsonn to get discord message no longer working

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py, bots

I have a bot that has been running for almost a year now reading discord messages in a server channel. It uses the following code to get new messages in json format:

```
r = requests.get(f'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channelid}/messages?limit=1', headers=headers)
jsonn = json.loads(r.text)
for value in jsonn:
    print(value)
    current = str(value['embeds'])[1:500]
    if current != last:
```

This same code now throws up the following error

```
"current = str(value['embeds'])[1:500]
TypeError: string indices must be integers"
```

I am not sure why it has stopped working. Can anyone please explain/help?

Comment: jsonn is a dict ? maybe your variable value is a string, u cant do value["string"] then

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else gets this - it is because my authorization expired and I had to insert a new one into the header. :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).